# A Possible Bug Concerning The Sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos(\pi k)}{\csc(\pi k)}$?

Tags: summation

> **Question**: [For reference see this post in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820111/wolframalpha-and-the-sum-sum-k-1n-frac-cos-pi-k-csc-pi-k).
> I noticed on WolframAlpha the summation $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos(\pi
> > k)}{\csc(\pi k)}$ returns the result $\phi(n)$; which is the Euler phi
> function. Of course this summation should equal zero. A commentator
> suggested it might be bug in WolframAlpha as the Mathematica code:
> Sum[Cos[Pi k]/Csc[Pi k], {k, 1, n}] returns 0. At least this was the
> case running on  Windows 10, x86, running version 12.1.1.0. Another
> commentator showed the same code returns EulerPhi[n] running version
> 12.0.0.0 on macOS. Is this a bug in Mathematica?

Comment: The code correctly returns zero in the current version, so there's no bug.  I also get `EulerPhi[n]` in V12.0, so there was a bug.

Comment: @MichaelE2 might you answerize that so I can accept your answer. Any guess what might be going on in WolframAlpha or in prior versions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version V12.1.1:

```
Sum[Cos[Pi k]/Csc[Pi k], {k, 1, n}]
```

> ```
> (*  0  *)
> ```

Version V12.0.0:

```
Sum[Cos[Pi k]/Csc[Pi k], {k, 1, n}]
```

> ```
> (*  EulerPhi[n]  *)
> ```

It seems there was a bug in the earlier version of V12.  It's possible that Wolfram|Alpha is using V12.0 (but questions about the workings of W|A are off-topic on this site).